# Getting the correct class when reading in ruby object from safe_yaml

Tags: ruby, oauth, yaml

I have a yaml file that stores the `OAuth::AccessToken` value returned by authenticating with the oauth gem.  I read this file in to save myself authenticating each time.

```
:access_token: !ruby/object:OAuth::AccessToken
  token: 0fXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  secret: eXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  consumer: !ruby/object:OAuth::Consumer
    key: 2aXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    secret: 181XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    options:
      :signature_method: HMAC-SHA1
      :request_token_path: /oauth/request_token/
      :authorize_path: /oauth/authorize
      :access_token_path: /oauth/access_token/
      :proxy: 
      :scheme: :header
      :http_method: :get
      :oauth_version: '1.0'
      :site: http://api.mendeley.com
    http_method: :get
    http: !ruby/object:Net::HTTP
      address: api.mendeley.com
      port: 80
      curr_http_version: '1.1'
      no_keepalive_server: false
      close_on_empty_response: false
      socket: 
      started: false
      open_timeout: 30
      read_timeout: 30
      continue_timeout: 
      debug_output: 
      use_ssl: false
      ssl_context: 
      enable_post_connection_check: true
      compression: 
      sspi_enabled: false
      ssl_version: 
      key: 
      cert: 
      ca_file: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
      ca_path: 
      cert_store: 
      ciphers: 
      verify_mode: 1
      verify_callback: 
      verify_depth: 5
      ssl_timeout: 
  params:
    :oauth_token: 0fXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    oauth_token: 0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    :oauth_token_secret: efXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    oauth_token_secret: eXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

When I read this file in using the `yaml` gem, everything works fine.  But I'm using Jekyll and have to read this in with `safe_yaml` gem, and even though the yaml appears to correctly dictate the class, when I do:

```
auth_contents = YAML::load(File.open("auth.yaml"))
$access_token = auth_contents[":access_token"]
```

I get `$access_token` back as a hash; the class declaration is lost.  This means that of course I cannot apply methods like `$access_token.get`, etc.  How can I work around this?  Any way to persuade ruby to recognize the correct class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Make sure that you actually want to load in the class. It appears to me like you control the YAML file, but if it for some reason is loaded from somewhere you don't trust, you probably want to manually deserialize the hash.

That said, you can [whitelist trusted types](https://github.com/dtao/safe_yaml#whitelisting-trusted-types) with `safe_yaml`:

```
SafeYAML.whitelist!(OAuth::AccessToken, OAuth::Consumer, Net::HTTP)
```